# When installing openEdx, why is there no error message but an installation failure message?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, openedx

I execute the following command:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/$OPENEDX_RELEASE/util/install/native.sh -O - | bash
```

At the end of the execution, there is no error message, only an installation failure message.

[image]